# CSV processing in Hadoop

Tags: java, csv, hadoop, mapreduce

I have 6 fields in a `csv` file:

- first is student name (`String`)
- others are student's marks like subject 1 , subject 2 etc

I am writing `mapreduce` in java, splitting all fields with comma and sending student name in key and marks in value of map.

In `reduce` I'm processing them outputting student name in key and theire marks plus total, average, etc in value of `reduce`.

I think there may be an alternative, and more efficient way to do this.

Has anyone got an idea of a better way to do this these operations?

Are there any inbuilt functions of `hadoop` which can group by student name and can calculate total marks and average associated to thaty student?

Comment: can you post a sample of your data and the desire output (with headers name). also, student name seems to be the key, is it unique in the file, is it showing only once?

Comment: No , there roll calls are.Because some students have got same first and last names.and i am not processing roll call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to have a look at Pig http://pig.apache.org/ which provides a simple language on top of Hadoop that lets you perform many standard tasks with *much* shorter code.

Comment: ok , will check it out.But will it carry overhead on hadoop??

Comment: It creates Hadoop queries. So there's a small overhead for the "translation" and it is possible that you'd come up with a more efficient way of writing the Hadoop code, so that might count as overhead. But your requirements seem pretty sane, so I'd trust that Pig is capable of finding an efficient solution for that.

Comment: one thing on efficiency. Pig's team claim pig scrips are more efficient than writing mapreduce in java, because they use technics than average developer do not know.

Comment: but of course everyone is better than the average developer ;)

Comment: I need like button to like comments here .<br>And Apache products must be coded well than avg developer. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Use HIVE.It simpler than writing mapreduce in java and might be me more familiar than PIG, since it's SQL like syntax.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/Home

What you have to do is 
1) install hive client in your machine or 1 node and point it to your cluster. 
2) create the tables description for that file 
3) load the data 
4) write the SQL. Since it think your data looks like student_name, subject_mark1, subject_mark2, etc you might need to use explode 
 https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF#LanguageManualUDF-explode

2) CREATE TABLE students(name STRING, subject1 INT,subject2 INT)
   ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
   FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   STORED AS SEQUENCEFILE;

3) LOAD DATA INPATH '/path/to/data/students.csv' INTO TABLE students;

4) SELECT name, AVG(subject1), AVG(subject2) FROM students GROUP BY name;

output might look like:

NAME   |  SUBJECT1 | SUBJECT 2

john   |    6.2    |   7.0

tom    |    3.5    |   5.0

Comment: I would prefer using Hbase.I am doing research on hadoop and related system , but i concluded that because of sql like queries Hive takes bit overhead on system.And i dont want to use mysql behind hive , because now my mysql is not capable of handling data.

Answer (score 0):

You can set your reducer to run as [combiner](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/HadoopMapReduce) in addition to running as a reducer so you can perform interim calculation before sending all to the reducer.

As Nicolas78 said you should consider looking at pig which does a pretty good job of building an efficient map/reduce and saving you both code and effort

Comment: Ok.. Currently i am using combiner.Apache say its a part of hadoop efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

> I am writing mapreduce in java, splitting all fields with comma and sending student name in key and marks in value of map.
>
> In reduce I'm processing them outputting student name in key and theire marks plus total, average, etc in value of reduce.

This can be easily written as a map only job, there is no need for a reducer. Once the mapper gets a row from the CSV, split them and calculate as required in the mapper only. And emit the student name as key and average/total etc as value.

Comment: But are there any inbuilt mathematical functions or csv formatting function ? that i can use and make program efficient.

Comment: How is this related to Hadoop? Definitely, there will be API for that. Post a separate query.