# HIVE installation on windows

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hive

I am new to Hadoop. I have installed hadoop on windows by following the link(not used cygwin) 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/757934/Apache-Hadoop-for-Windows-Platform.

I want to process a csv file. In few blog it is written as to use HIVE for CSV file. Or is there any other way to process the file.

Can someone help me to install hive and how to write a mapreduce program for a particular column?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

you can use PIG to process your file also.PIG helps to cleanse the data.It depends which kind of processing you want to do on your data.Below link can give you idea on CSV processing in HDFS

[CSV processing in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8630837/csv-processing-in-hadoop)

below link can give you idea in HIVE installation in windows

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/AdminManual+Installation